# Directory.GetFiles() pattern match in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, directory-listing

I'm using `Directory.GetFiles()` to list files according to given pattern. This works fine for most of patterns I'm looking for (e.g. zip, rar, sfv).

This is how I prepare the list (more or less). The problem is with pattern of numbers .001 to .999 that I want to list.

```
alArrayPatternText.Add("*.zip");
alArrayPatternText.Add("*.sfv");
alArrayPatternText.Add("*.r??");
alArrayPatternText.Add("*.001");
for (int i = 2; i <= 999; i++)
{
    string findNumber = String.Format("{0:000}", i);
    alArrayPatternText.Add("*." + findNumber);
}
```

I then call

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(strDirName, varPattern);
```

for each pattern in the Array which seems like very bad idea to do so since the list has 1002 entries and checking if directory has each of them is just a bit too time consuming.

Would there be a better way to do so ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call `Directory.EnumerateFiles("path", "*")` and then use LINQ to filter the paths by calling `Path.GetExtension`.

For example:

```
var extensions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    ".zip", ".sfv"
};
extensions.UnionWith(Enumerable.Range(1, 998).Select(i => i.ToString(".000")));
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("path", "*")
            .Where(p => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(p))
                     || Path.GetExtension(p).StartsWith(".r", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Thanks, that should do it :-)

Comment: Hrmms, there seems to be something wrong, the 000-999 doesn't get converted nicely. It shows as 1,000 2,000 etc and even thou the dir has zip files and 001 doesn't return anything for files.. :/

Comment: Probably a string format issue. Try replacing: i => i.ToString(".000") with: i => "." + i

Comment: Yes that was string format issue but i replace it with `i => String.Format(".{0:000}", i)` and it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

My final method based on SLaks answer for anyone looking for similar solution

```
private static IEnumerable<string> DirectoryGetFiles(string strDirName, SearchOption varOption) {
var extensions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { ".zip", ".sfv" };
     extensions.UnionWith(Enumerable.Range(1, 999).Select(i => String.Format(".{0:000}", i)));
     extensions.UnionWith(Enumerable.Range(1, 99).Select(i => String.Format(".r{0:00}", i)));
     extensions.UnionWith(Enumerable.Range(1, 99).Select(i => String.Format(".s{0:00}", i)));
     extensions.UnionWith(Enumerable.Range(1, 99).Select(i => String.Format(".t{0:00}", i)));
     return Directory.EnumerateFiles(strDirName, "*.*", varOption).Where(p => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(p))).ToList();
}
```