# How to add multiple files using Directory.GetFiles() in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This question might have been asked before, however I am not able to pass three parameters in single loop which I need for my method. I have like thousands of files in that directory (xml,jpg,tiff) (mixed).

This is something what I'm trying to get.

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var path = @"d:\xmlfiles";
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                ProcessFile(file,param2,param3);
            }

        }

    static void ProcessFile(string file_xml, string file_jpg, string file_tiff)
        {
            // do processing here...
            //Adding data to sql
        }
```

I tried `Path.GetExtension`, but it only gives extension. I have to pass file name and the logic is in the method `Processfile()`.

I saw many questions asked before which only returns single file.
Any other way for a workaround?

- [Directory.GetFiles() method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964912/directory-getfiles-method-in-c-sharp)
- [Directory.getfiles(): specific names of files c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547616/directory-getfiles-specific-names-of-files-c-sharp)
- [Multiple filters with Directory.GetFiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603363/multiple-filters-with-directory-getfiles)
- [Directory.GetFiles() pattern match in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423429/directory-getfiles-pattern-match-in-c-sharp)

Any helpe would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You must add an example directory listing (2-3 files is enough) with the expected output.

Comment: I don't understand what these parameters should be. Are you just trying to process files with the extensions xml, gif and jpeg?

Comment: You should clarify what you expect to be in common among these different files? For example, do you have:
- file1.xml
- file1.jpg
- file1.tiff

or not necessarily?

Comment: @Steve yes. Eg. 1.xml, 1.jpg, 1.tiff

Comment: @Fabio M. Sorry I forgot to add the expectation.

Comment: So, if you have a file named MyData.xml, you have also a file named MyData.jpg ed a file named MyData.tiff? If this is the case you have your answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a directory containing files like this:

- `Foo.xml`, `Foo.jpg`, `Foo.tiff`
- `Bar.xml`, `Bar.jpg`, `Bar.tiff`
- `Baz.xml`, `Baz.jpg`, `Baz.tiff`

And you want to process equally named files together. Then why not pick and enumerate one extension, and reconstruct the accompanying file names:

```
foreach (var xmlFile in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml"))
{
    var extensionLess = Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension(xmlFile);

    var jpgFile = Path.Combine(path, extensionLess + ".jpg");
    var tiffFile = Path.Combine(path, extensionLess + ".tiff");

    ProcessFile(xmlFile, jpgFile, tiffFile);
}
```

Comment: Should do the same treatment to the `xml` file so it doesn't have the full path. I am guessing he wants the same format for the 3 files.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you for big help!! and I didn't know of "GetFilenameWithoutExtension" I only tried GetFiles() which I knew from other questions. Thanks.